# How Can I Send HTML string to Backend?

Tags: html, reactjs, json, service, axios

I am using NextJs,  I have a rich text editor my frontEnd. This output is html when i try to send this html with axios request to backend. I am getting error because format it is not json.

How can i send this html to backend service ? Is there any way ?

I download cheerio but ı don't understand.

Comment: Did you try to encode it?

Comment: share your code and your attempt so we can help

Comment: Well it's not JSON, it's HTML. So you should probably encode it and use the `text/html` content type header for that route

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to encode the HTML string using this function:

```
const escapeHTML = function(str){
  str.replace(/[&<>'"]/g, 
  tag => ({
      '&': '&amp;',
      '<': '&lt;',
      '>': '&gt;',
      "'": '&#39;',
      '"': '&quot;'
    }[tag]));
}
```

To decode the HTML string, you can use:

```
const decodeHTML = function(html) {
    let txt = document.createElement('textarea');
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
};
```

Or:

```
const decodeHTML = function(input) {   
  let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");   
  return doc.documentElement.textContent; 
}  

console.log(  decodeHTML("&lt;img src='img.jpg'&gt;")  )     
//Output: "<img src='img.jpg'>"
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing answer  I will try, how can i decode ?

Comment: I have updated the answer, added 2 ways to decode the parsed HTML string